# How do I remedy "Error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close'"?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, karma-runner

I was going about business as usual and about to checkout generator-angular-fullstack.

I got no red errors but a message at the end saying `Error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close'`. I tried many a-thing–uninstalling node, reinstalling, manually getting rid of files and directories in local and/or global paths and tried to make sure Homebrew was the one who installed everything and somehow I've made things worse.

(Also, I initially saw errors regarding karma. Everything looked right but it doesn't seem I did any good by throwing commands at it.)

I am at a loss. All the stackoverflow questions have been clicked and I'm afraid I've probably tried too many of the suggestions. I cannot install any Yeoman generator. I cannot install anything with npm. When inside the project directory when I run npm install it throws the error. I really have no clue. Is there a way I can basically start over all together? A simple uninstall and install isn't cutting it. Something in the system needs to change but I don't know what. Any ideas?

## EDIT

---

I don't have a thorough list of how I ended up getting Node back in working order, but [this Homebrew issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28501#issuecomment-41956380) was really informative & helpful. I don't know how my permissions got out of whack, it was likely my own fault. This didn't fix everything though, I was still getting child-process-close errors. Looking through issues on NPM's github, I found [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5133), which tells how to manually remove package.tgz. The short is run `rm /Users/tylersloan/.npm/connect/2.8.8/package.tgz`. Viola!

Answer (score 39):

You’ll want to remove the `node_modules` folder using this command:

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then re-install `node`:

```
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
```

That brings `npm` back to life.

Answer (score 8):

On my machine, I had to make a couple of adjustments to @Believe2014 's response

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

And then reinstall node as `sudo`

```
$ brew uninstall node
$ sudo brew install node
```

Then `npm` behaved as expected for me, for example to install the [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) framework:

```
sudo npm install -g sails
```

Comment: Just to add my experience; brew refused to install as sudo but following your steps without the sudo in the node install still corrected the issue.

I was getting the problem when trying to install react-native-cli

Answer (score 5):

Before re-installing node, make sure also that `child-process-promise` is added in package.json using this command:

```
npm install child-process-promise --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on MAC os

I was following the above solution but did not get rid of this issue.

I unintall node by brew uninstall node  things I downloaded the node setup from https://nodejs.org/en/ and installed it(not with brew). Now everything working perfectly.

It was the issue with the installed file path.

Answer (score 1):

1) Change directory using `cd functions`
  2) then install npm pack with `npm install request-promise` (did not work for me, but you try it)
  3)alternatively, do `npm i child-process-promise` (Worked fine for me!)
[child-process-promise npm package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise)
  4) finally you can run: `firebase deploy`