# Webpack Cannot find module 'loader-utils'?

Tags: webpack

I have imported my css file to main.js which is the entry file for webpack.

```
require('../css/main.css');
```

And I installed style&css loaders.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"}
    ]
},
```

**style-loader and webpack already have loader-utils package under their node_modules folder but it still cant find this module?**

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'loader-utils' @ ./public/css/main.css 4:14-78
```

Comment: That sounds like a messed up `node_modules` folder to me. Have you tried to turn it off and on again aka `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm i`?

Comment: yea i tried it and  its fixed now, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remedy "Error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966060/how-do-i-remedy-error-cannot-find-module-child-process-close)

Answer (score 3):

Just do `npm i loader-utils`. That's what worked for me.